# mysqli's bind_param using an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert values into a database using mysqli prepared statements.  The values that will be inserted will vary at runtime, so I am trying to use variables instead of listing out all the parameters. I have seen that I can use call_user_func_array to achieve this, but this doesn't seem to work.

My code so far is below, albeit greatly reduced and modified for simplicity:

```
// in the real world, these will be set dynamically
$table = 'my_table';
$sql_fields = 'field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4';
$sql_types = 'ssss';
$sql_holders = '?,?,?,?';
$data = array('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4');

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($sql_fields) VALUES ($sql_holders)");
$params = array_merge(array($sql_types), $data);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $params);
```

If I var_dump $params, I get the following.

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "ssss"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "value_1"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "value_2"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "value_3"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "value_4"
}
```

This all seems okay to me, yet when I run the script, PHP crashes. I can comment out the "call_user_func_array" line and it works. Obviously nothing happens, but it doesn't crash.

I am afraid I don't know too much about my environment, except that I am using PHP 7, PhpStorm IDE and WAMP. When PHP crashes, I get the PhpStorm error "CLI has stopped working". My research tells me that this error is a PHP crashing and not the IDE, so the problem should be with my code. (incidentally, I have tried this on two machines running PhpStorm and get the same result, so this research seems to be validated)

Is anyone able to shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that PDO makes this considerably easier since `execute()` takes an array argument, no fancy dancing required.

Comment: check server logs, your solution should work, need to find the error

Comment: you also have an answer waiting for you, see that. check for errors on the query and with error reporting

Comment: [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42373791/1415724) below works. If you tried it and it still doesn't work, then you have errors somewhere and a probable indexing issue. Btw, did you leave the question only to return at a future date? You've been given comments and an answer but no response for anything.

Comment: @Roman *"your solution should work"* -  Actually it won't work and they should have gotten the following error: `Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given...`. Ivan's answer below is the solution to this.

Comment: @Fred -ii- No, I planned to come back to it now, but I got called away from my desk for a while.

Comment: @Typhoon101 ah, that's what I thought (Spidey sense), which is why I now ask the OPs if they left only to return later, it happens ;-) Glad to see this all worked out, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this, to send reference to values instead of real values:

```
    $params = array_merge(array($sql_types), $data);
    foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {
        $params[$key] = &$params[$key];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $params);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I am not entirely sure why, but it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: mine says `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object ` I've used the exact code!! PHP-7, WAMP