# Check if all values in array are in database and store ones that aren't in new array

Tags: php, arrays, database, logic

I have an array that looks something like this -> ["john.smith@gmail.com", "jane.doe@gmail.com", "jack.smith@gmail.com"]. I want to increment $count for each email that exists in the database. If it doesn't exist (invalid), then I want to push it to the $invalidEmails array.

After that, I want to set my $output according to whether all the emails in the original array are valid or not. They're valid if all of them exist in the database. I'd appreciate some help with this as I'm not sure how to go about it from here. It doesn't work for all cases right now, for example if first email is valid but second one is invalid.

This is what I have so far:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT mail FROM dej_colleagues");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$tags = preg_split("/\,/", $_POST['tags']);
$invalidEmails = array();
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tags); $i++) {
    $trim_brackets = trim($tags[$i], '[]');
    $trim_quotes = trim($trim_brackets, '"');
    
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if ($trim_quotes == $row["mail"]) {
            $count += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($count == 0) {
        array_push($invalidEmails, $tags[$i]);
    }
}
$output = array();
if (sizeof($tags) == $count) {
    $output = array("validity => "valid emails");
}
else {
    $output = array("validity" => "invalid emails", "emails" => $invalidEmails;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: It's difficult to see what is supposed to be happening here. Please post some sample data showing what you start with and the results you expect.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I updated my question. Let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems convoluted, so rather than debug it I started with a more focussed query and worked from there.

Basically, the query asks the database for a list of emails that appear in your `$tags` array, then uses `array_diff()` to find any that appear in $tags, but not in the database.

From there you can produce your output directly.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql.lv.local','userName', 'userPassword','schemaName' );

// Assuming the input is a string and not an array, json_decode it.
$tags = '["john.smith@gmail.com", "Jane.doe@gmail.com", "jack.smith@gmail.com","fred.jones@gmail.com"]';
$tags = json_decode($tags);
// switch everything to lower case
$tags = array_map('strtolower', $tags);

// Build and prepare a query with placeholders. Note conversion to lower case
$sql = 'select distinct lower(`mail`) from `emails` where lower(`mail`) in (?'.str_repeat(',?', count($tags)-1).')';
//echo $sql;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// Bind the values from $tags to the query
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($tags)), ...$tags);
// Execute
$stmt->execute();
// Bind a variable for the result
$stmt->bind_result($email);
// Retrieve the emails in to $dbMails
$dbMails = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $dbMails[] = $email;
}
//var_dump($dbMails);
// Anything that's in $tags but not in $dbMails is invalid
$absentEmails = array_diff($tags, $dbMails);
//var_dump($absentEmails);

if ($absentEmails) {
    $op= ["validity"=>"Invalid enails", 'emails'=>array_values($absentEmails)];
} else {
    $op= ["validity"=>"Valid enails"];
}
echo json_encode($op);
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522025/check-if-all-values-in-an-array-exist-in-a-database-column You might want to move your answer there